# How to recognize for the same face?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, face-recognition

My app has the ability to store passwords. But these are important passwords, so I do not want the user to be hacked. I thought of being able to use facial recognition, than answering security questions **or** a passcode to enter. I am fine with the last two options, just stuck on facial recognition.

I have setup the view as a full camera view.

How can I perform facial recognition, is there an API out there, or some sample code? How can I make sure it is the same face I see?

One last thing, will holding up a picture recognize the face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facial recognition is a bad idea to store | recover any kind of important data…

Even if you have the best recognition algorithm, a simple picture can break your security!

But… answering to your question, Apple has released a face recognition API to iOS 6… to older iOS, you'll probably have to create your own algorithm.

Facial recognition algorithms are usually based on eye, eyebrow, nose-point and mouth distances.

Comment: really? I am a developer, I do have Xcode 4.5, could you lead me to some documentation?

Comment: You can check something here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataFaceObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVMetadataFaceObject/faceID

Or here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIFaceFeature/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010976

Comment: But… as I said, I don't think it's a good idea to recover passwords… maybe a nice eye candy, but very insecure!

Comment: Ok, but there is facial recognition THEN you HAVE to answer security answers OR a password. Is it AVMetadataFaceObject

Comment: Nice… I wasn't sure witch one was the right one for your needs.

Comment: Do you have any demo for face recognition API or any idea how to implement it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the face.com API and send a photo to them to be recognized. I believe they pull data from Facebook for the face recognition, so you may need your user to Facebook connect. Check out the docs for yourself.

Full disclosure: face.com gave me a t-shirt once.

Yes, holding up a picture will recognize the face.

Comment: Ok, but what if the user has no profile pictures on Facebook of himself or literally doesn't have Facebook....

Comment: What I want to do is just recognize if it is the same face

Comment: The user registers his face at the start, I need to check when the user reopens the app later if it is the same face. I had an idea, to store these two things to the user defaults: the distance between eyes, and distance between left eye and mouth and distance between right eye and mouth. Will that be the same each time? Should be right...

Comment: When the user reopens the app, display a lock screen and ask them to take another photo of their face.

Comment: You can use face.com without facebook, using a private namespace.

Comment: To check the distance, you'll have to know the focal distance… I don't know if the camera API give you that, but I believe it does…

So, you'll have to compensate the distance from the camera to the user. And, you need some error correction, as the measuring is not that accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently gone through this exercise, if you want to use basic capabilities offered by the Apple framework you use the CIDetector with type CIDetectorTypeFace and then iterate through the returned CIFaceFeatures array. I created a struct called Features to store eyes and mouth positions:

```
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil options:                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh  forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];
NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

Features *face = [[Features alloc] init]; //simple struct with 3 face points

for( CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
    {
      //use _faceView to compare view of 2nd image as one will have to be scaled to the others size
       _faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFeature.bounds];
       if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition)
       {
           face.leftEye = faceFeature.leftEyePosition;

          // do the same for face.rightEye, and face.Mouth
          .
          .
          .
```

After you have the base face's coordinates you can compare the distances between eyes and mouth and decide at which percentage is a match. You could add blink detection to ensure it's a person and not a copied image. But thats a topic for another thread